# nfs entry in /etc/fstab fails but manually mounting works

Tags: nfs, nfsclient, fstab

Client is Ubuntu Xenial, manually mounting works just fine:

```
mount 10.0.0.12:/mnt/d1 /mnt/d1
```

I then copy that line from /etc/mtab to /etc/fstab:

```
10.0.0.12:/mnt/d1 /mnt/d1 nfs4 user,rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.0.0.23,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.12 0 0

umount /mnt/d1
```

and then mount it again using fstab:

```
mount /mnt/d1
```

and it times out at that time.

The  nfs server is centos7

Updated firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=nfs
```

and reloaded,  with /etc/exports like so:

```
/mnt/d1           10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are a few other firewall ports to enable:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=mountd
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=rpc-bind
```

Go ahead and ensure all services are enabled too:

```
systemctl enable rpcbind
systemctl enable nfs-server
systemctl enable nfs-lock
systemctl enable nfs-idmap
systemctl start rpcbind
systemctl start nfs-server
systemctl start nfs-lock
systemctl start nfs-idmap
```

And check the perms on your mount point:

```
ls -lh /mnt
```